# New way to generet random numbers but

Tags: c, arrays, random

I am trying to find 6 number one is from 10-100 and the other five numbers are between 1-10
 the articles that I read  about generating new numbers was somehow complex for me to apply so I made a new simple way by obtaining a series of repetitions of these numbers  and put them in two-dimensional array after that I used rand() as index to the first array parameter so I could find the random numbers   but I have a problem ..I want to put the generated numbers  in array because I want to use them later.

I'll be thankful if you explain in a simple way

```
include<sys/time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h> 
#include<ctime>
#define max 1000

int main()
{    
    int o, gr1num1[max][1] ,n=6,q[max] ,i = 0, gr2num5[max][5];

    while(1)
    {       
        i++;
        gr2num5[i][4] = rand() % 10+1 ;
        if(i == 1000)
            break;
    }

    if (gr2num5 [i][4]!=0) 
        srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\ngroup 2 numbers %d  ",gr2num5 [rand()%500][4]);
    printf("\ngroup 2 numbers %d  ",gr2num5 [rand()%500][4]);
    printf("\ngroup 2 numbers %d  ",gr2num5 [rand()%500][4]);
    printf("\ngroup 2 numbers %d  ",gr2num5 [rand()%500][4]);
    printf("\ngroup 2 numbers %d  ",gr2num5 [rand()%500][4]);

    printf("   \n\n\n /// %d /// ",o);

    while(1)
    {       
        i++;
        gr1num1[i][1] = rand() % 100+10;
        if(i == 1000)
            break;
    }

    printf("group 1 number %d",gr1num1 [rand()%500][1]);
}
```

Comment: Explain... what?

Comment: how to put the generated number in array

Comment: Asides: 1): you should call `srand` *before* the first use of `rand`. 2) having `#define max 1000` you should use it instead of `if(i==1000)`.

Comment: Your second `while` loop will break because you didn't reset `i = 0;` before it. This is a reason to use a test such as `if(i >= max)` instead of `if(i == max)` - to stop runaway code.

Comment: when i change the code as you mention it gives 0 for the second loop

Comment: your array `gr1num1` doesn't need to be 2 dimensional and your second index only goes up to 0 (it only has a size of 1) so doing `gr1num1[i][1]` will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: i did this because i wanted to choose randomly number of 1000 group like if i make it from one dimensional i'll have the same number always

Comment: That's like a 100-word run-on sentence. Please try to write your questions well enough that people can read them without having to strain their eyes and brain to understand where the punctuation should be. Even then, I'm not sure it's evident what you're asking.

Comment: Also, you tagged this as `c`, but this line begs to differ: `#include<ctime>`. That's a C++ header. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

First off you should go back and re-read your book on C for how to do loops as whilst syntactically correct, the way you're using those `while` loops isn't right.

This is how your first `while` loop should look. The increment of `i` happens at the end of the loop since the index of arrays starts at 0.

```
i=0;
while(i<max)
{
    gr2num5[i][4]= rand() % 10+1 ;
    i++;
}
```

But really it would be better done as a `for` loop like this as it wraps up the initialisation, conditional and incrementation all in one neat package. The first part - the initialisation - is important as for your second `while` loop, your value of `i` is still 1000 as you don't reset it to 0.

```
for(i=0;i<max;i++)
{
    gr2num5[i][4]= rand() % 10+1 ;
}
```

But you're after 5 values, so you need to nest two loops within each other to populate the `gr2num5` array like this.

```
for(i=0;i<max;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        gr2num5[i][j]=rand() % 10+1 ;
    }
}
```

(NB: you'll define `j` at the top along side `i`)